# attr_accessor - Accessing an objects attributes from another class

Tags: ruby, object, attributes

I want to access the ogre's object's swings attribute from the Human's class.  However, all I am getting is:
`NameError: undefined local variable or method ogre for
**<Human:0x007fdb452fb4f8 @encounters=3, @saw_ogre=true>`
Most likely a simple solution, and my brain is just not operating this morning.  I am running tests with minitest.  The test and classes are below:

## ogre_test.rb

```
def test_it_swings_the_club_when_the_human_notices_it
  ogre = Ogre.new('Brak')
  human = Human.new
  ogre.encounter(human)
  assert_equal 0, ogre.swings
  refute human.notices_ogre?

  ogre.encounter(human)
  ogre.encounter(human)

  assert_equal 1, ogre.swings
  assert human.notices_ogre?
end
```

## ogre.rb

```
class Ogre
  attr_accessor :swings
  def initialize(name, home='Swamp')
    @name = name
    @home = home
    @encounters = 0
    @swings =  0
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def home
    @home
  end

  def encounter(human)
    human.encounters
  end

  def encounter_counter
    @encounters
  end

  def swing_at(human)
    @swings += 1
  end

  def swings
    @swings
  end
end


class Human

  def initialize(encounters=0)
    @encounters = encounters
    @saw_ogre = false
  end

  def name
    "Jane"
  end

  def encounters
    @encounters += 1
    if @encounters % 3 == 0 and @encounters != 0
      @saw_ogre = true
    else
      @saw_ogre = false
    end
    if @saw_ogre == true
      ogre.swings += 1 # <----issue
    end
  end

  def encounter_counter
    @encounters
  end

  def notices_ogre?
   @saw_ogre
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix would be to pass the ogre object as an argument to `encounters` - assuming `encounters` isn't used anywhere else without the argument.

```
class Ogre
  ...

  def encounter(human)
    human.encounters(self)
  end

  ...    
end


class Human
  ...

  def encounters(ogre)
    @encounters += 1
    if @encounters % 3 == 0 and @encounters != 0
      @saw_ogre = true
    else
      @saw_ogre = false
    end
    if @saw_ogre == true
      ogre.swings += 1 # <----issue
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: THANKS! So, since I wasn't passing the argument, it couldn't be used.  Was the basis of how I was trying to use attr_accessor in theory correct?

Comment: It's 'a way' to do it. There are multiple but this looks fine to me.

Comment: @Prodigy_Internet: as this answer explains, you had a simple scope problem. The `attr_accessor` doesn't even enter into the picture at all. But, since you are asking: no, this is absolutely terrible. You are allowing anyone to arbitrarily change the value of `swings` by assigning any number to it. It's not quite clear what you want to achieve with that information, but here are two ideas: if you are using it to check whether the ogre is tired, I can simply win any fight by setting it to some ridiculously high value first. If you are using it to count how often the ogre has hit me, I can win …

Comment: … any fight by setting it to 0. You should *never* expose data to let others fiddle with. You should expose behavior, and only fiddle with your data yourself. Just like in real life, you don't run around exposing your private parts to everybody!

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand your point but for somebody who's just (probably) probing around Ruby this is not 'absolutely terrible'. I can think of examples to solve this problem which are way more horrible than how he's currently doing it. Also I think the way you're currently writing, is really really demotivating. Just write it down in a way that this guy can actually learn something. Just say, I see "A", I think it would be better if you did "B" because of reason "C".